# python: I get InvalidToken error while using bucket.objects.filter(Prefi=myPrefixString) in boto3 1.7.21

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto, boto3, botocore

I am trying to access objects from my s3 bucket. Iam using boto3 1.7.21. First I created a session using

```
session = boto3.session.Session(aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
                  aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key,
                  region_name=region_name)
```

then trying to get objects by a filter using

```
session.resources("s3").Bucket(myBucketName)
.objects.filter(Prefix=myPrefix)
```

I get the below error

```
ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidToken) when calling the ListObjects operation: The provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid.
```

My dev versions:

- python - 2.7,
- boto3 - 1.7.21,
- botocore - 1.10.35

Answer (score 0):

A better approach to do the same is to download and use **AWS CLI** and run the command **aws configure** to save your ***access_key_id*** , ***secret_access_key*** and default ***region*** in your local machine and then run this python script given below :

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket=s3.Bucket('bucket_name')

for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='Event/'):
    print(obj.key)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs if you pass the wrong session token.  In your case, you did not include it.

```
session = boto3.session.Session(
   aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
   aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key,
   region_name=region_name, 
   aws_session_token=aws_session_token)
```